# Why can't I see any changes in my "Place" tab

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-studio, debugging

I want each tab to to show something different.  To start things off, I want to make changes to the `Place` tab.  The problem is, none of the changes are being reflected in the Android Simulator.

Image of what I'm referring to

In this case, I want the text `something` to show up, but it's not.  What am I doing wrong?  I've also included code that might be relevant to this issue.

Here's `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Place.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Profile.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Take.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Place"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Take"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Profile"));

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Here's `fragment_place.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Place"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Something" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's `PagerAdapter.java`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int mNoOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNoOfTabs = NumberOfTabs; // set global number of tabs to local number of tabs
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                Place place = new Place();
                return place;
            case 1:
                Profile profile = new Profile();
                return profile;
            case 2:
                Take take = new Take();
                return take;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your PagerAdapter and fragment that dosent reflect changes

Comment: @EmreAktürk just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code where you provide the layout xml to the fragment

Comment: ah, how would I do that?

Comment: View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout. fragment_place, null);

And then :

tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view);

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines to given code.

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
    return mNoOfTabs ;
 }
```

Also make sure you inflate the layout belong to Place (Fragment) `onViewCreated()` method